# How do I make a for loop that makes a new variable everytime

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables, indexing, var

I'm trying to make a game where it spawns in 3 blocks at random x positions that all have there own x, y, w, h what I'm wondering is how to have it make a block0 var, block1 var and a block2 var in a for loop here's what I've got:

```js
function block() {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;

  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
}
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var block[i] = new block(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) * 100,0,100,100);
  block[i]();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array for hold your blocks. Also, I have added the related arguments to the `block()` function.

```
function block(x, y, w, h)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;

    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
}

let blocks = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    blocks[i] = new block(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) * 100, 0, 100, 100);
    // or blocks.push(new block(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) * 100, 0, 100, 100));
}
```

Then, later, you can access the three blocks as `blocks[0]`, `blocks[1]` and `blocks[2]` respectively.

Comment: I'm assuming this person already did declare the array, but just didn't include it in the scope of their posted code. If not, then that's a rather amusingly simple solution.

Comment: @MaxVoisard But he tried to define a new variable like `var block[i]` on each iteration of the loop, I don't believe he uses an array.

Comment: you're quite possibly right. He also tried to defined a variable with the array's index in it, not the array itself, which is why it would just keep redefining different values for the same variable.